# How can I use libssl with Cocoa on Lion?

Tags: cocoa, osx-lion, libssl

I'm linking against a static library build from source, and including local headers, not the headers in `/usr/include`, but Xcode still lists may functions as depreciated, and it's failing to find symbols. Has anyone gotten libssl working on Lion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep, SSL functions are deprecated on Lion.

You should use stuff from **CommonCrypto** instead. Basically, it has replacements for all SSL functions, and they are usually compatible.

For instance, if you use MD5 (openssl/md5.h), you'll get those deprecated warnings.
You can the include CommonDigest, and use CC_MD5_* functions, instead of the old MD5_* ones.

You should also be able to produce a compatibility header, to support other systems.
Something like:

```
#if defined( __APPLE__ )

    #include <CommonCrypto/CommonDigest.h>

    #ifdef MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH

        #undef MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH

    #endif

    #define MD5_Init            CC_MD5_Init
    #define MD5_Update          CC_MD5_Update
    #define MD5_Final           CC_MD5_Final
    #define MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH   CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH
    #define MD5_CTX             CC_MD5_CTX

#else

    #include <openssl/md5.h>

#endif
```

This is only for MD5, but you should be able to do the some for most other functions.

**EDIT**

CommonCrypto only support symmetric encryption, through CCCryptor.

If you need asymmetric encryption, you should use the [Security framework](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Security/Reference/SecurityFrameworkReference/_index.html).

Be sure to take a look at the Security [Transforms Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Security/Conceptual/SecTransformPG/Introduction/Introduction.html).

Comment: I'm willing to do that, but I cannot seem to find their asymmetric key API. Am I just not finding the right header?

Comment: thanks! Do you also happen to know how to convert a public SecKey to CFData and back? I found some examples using CSSM_KEY, but it was depreciated in 10.7 too.

Comment: i don't understand. if i am developing code for OS X that needs to be portable to other systems (e.g. Linux) it sounds like there is going to be a lot of OS (X) specific code for the asymmetric part.  what was the rationale behind Apple making all this extra work for developers to create cross-platform code?

Comment: You'll have the same issues trying to develop code on Linux that needs to be portable on OS X or other Unix-based systems... Linux is clearly NOT a reference in such a situation, as it unfortunately implies so many non-standard stuff, while claiming compatibility with *NIX systems... Remember OS X is fully POSIX compatible, as well as SUS... Linux is NOT...

Answer (score 0):

For anyone coming after me, Apple's Security Framework has what you are looking for, particularly `SecKeyGeneratePair`, `SecItemCopyMatching` (to get keys from the keychain), `SecItemExport` (to export to a PEM format), and `SecKeyCreateFromData` (to make a key from an NSData). Sign and verify are both done with `SecTransform`s. Apple has reasonable documentation for all of these functions if you search for the right terms.